# Why does copy/paste is lost as soon as the origin app is closed?

Tags: linux, gnome, copy-paste

I mean, who thoughts this would be a great idea?

If you open a file in, say Gedit, copy some text, close Gedit THEN paste somewhere, it doesn't work. This is the stupidest user experience never implemented, and I'm surprised it comes from Linux/Gnome.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to avoid it? Like an option to toggle to save the copy in actual memory, that can be accessed WHENEVER I want, not up to when I close the original window?

... I can't believe I'm asking this ..

Comment: Have you tried looking at [different clipboard managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#List_of_clipboard_managers)?

Comment: It comes from X, not Linux/Gnome.

Comment: Thank you @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. Why X decided to implement this? Do they published a valid reason for that? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Thanks! Do you have one you'd recommend?

Comment: https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  that link refers to selections, not copied text, which is what I assume the OP is talking about.  I don't see this (in XFCE) when say, opening a file in geany, copying some text, closing geany,  opening mousepad and pasting the text.  Copy/paste either by Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V or using the context menu. I don't know Gedit, but that's what I was going to blame.

Comment: @mcalex: There is no such thing as "copied text" in X. It is *all* selections. The only issue is who currently owns them and if they're still running.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection) article on selections may also help, it mentions `xclipboard`.